# UNION case containing FILTER NOT EXISTS and OPTIONAL doesn't produce results?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I have a query that selects some items.  If these items belong to a specific class (:UserSuitability), then I need to check if the user is also from the same class. There are four possible scenarios:

1. The item is from a class that is rdfs:subClassOf :UserSuitability, and the user is also from the same class. Then check if the item contains a value for hasSuitabilityValue and assign it to the variable ?suitabilityValue.
2. The item is from a class that is rdfs:subClassOf :UserSuitability, but the user is not, then check if the item contains a value for hasSuitabilityNotValue and assign it to the variable ?suitabilityValue.
3. The item is not from a class that is rdfs:subClassOf: UserSuitability, then assign 1 to the variable ?suitabilityValue.

   4. The item is not from a class that is rdfs:subClassOf:UserSuitability, and neither is the user.  In this case, do nothing.

My query so far, and the data to test it with are provided below.  Note that :item1 in the data should match the left hand side of the union, while :item2 should match the right hand side.  It seems that the right hand side never matches.

#### Data

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticrecommender.com/rs#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

:user1 a :class1 .
:user1 :likes :item1 .
:user1 :likes :item2 .
:class1 rdfs:subClassOf :UserSuitability .
:item1 a :class1 .
:item1 :hasSuitabilityWeight 1.5 .
:item1 :hasNotSuitabilityWeight 0.5 .
:item2 a :class2 .
:class2 rdfs:subClassOf :UserSuitability .
```

#### Query

```sql
prefix : <http://www.semanticrecommender.com/rs#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?item ?suitabilityValue where
{
  values ?user {:user1}
  ?user :likes ?item

  optional{
    #-- check if the item is from a class that is
    #-- rdfs:subClassOf :UserSuitability
    ?item a ?suitabilityClass.
    ?suitabilityClass rdfs:subClassOf :UserSuitability.
    {
      #-- if the user is also from the same class
      ?user a ?suitabilityClass
        optional{
        #-- check if the item has a value for :hasSuitabilityWeight
        ?item :hasSuitabilityWeight ?suitabilityValueOptional.
      }
      #-- if it does, assign it to the variable
      #-- ?suitabilityValue, otherwise, assign 1
      #-- to the variable suitabilityValue
      bind(if(bound(?suitabilityValueOptional), ?suitabilityValueOptional, 1) as ?suitabilityValue)

    }
    union
    {
      #-- if the user is not from the same class
      filter not exists {?user a ?suitabilityClass}
      optional{
        #-- if the item has a value to hasNotSuitabilityWeight
        ?item :hasNotSuitabilityWeight ?suitabilityNotValueOptional.
      }
      #-- assign it to suitabilityValue, otherwise, assign 0
      bind(if(bound(?suitabilityNotValueOptional), ?suitabilityNotValueOptional, 0) as ?suitabilityValue)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the closing.  It's reopened now.

Comment: Oooo.. this is a fun one, you're going to like this

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor thanks for answering, and reopen, :) I am in shopping, and I will check once at home again

Comment: Well, I did cast the final **closing** vote, too, so it was really just undoing my mistake.  You'll see in my answer, though, that you can reproduce the issue with a simpler test case;  the query you provided (and some of it's formatting) did make it easy to get confused about the placement of the bind form.  That said, this **is** a pretty weird issue, and it took me a while to see what it was, too.

Comment: Just goes to show how important it is to make sure your example is not just complete (and verifiable), but also _minimal_ :) Anyway, well spotted Joshua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I tried to recreate this problem from scratch, and ended up  with data that's very similar to yours, although a little bit simpler.  Here's the data I ended up using, which lets me avoid some of the filtering on whether a class is actually suitable or not.

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:user a :A ;
      :likes :i , :j .

:i a :A ;
   :hasValueYes 1 ;
   :hasValueNo  2 .

:j a :B .
```

Now, here's the query that's like yours;  it only gets a result for one of the two items, even though it seems like the other should match.  There's one commented line that I'll explain afterward.

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?item ?value {
  values ?user { :user }

  ?user :likes ?item .
  ?item a ?itemClass .

  {
    ?user a ?itemClass
    optional {
      ?item :hasValueYes ?valueYes
    }
    bind(if(bound(?valueYes), ?valueYes, "default yes value") as ?value)
  }
  union
  {
    #-- ?item ?anyP ?anyO   # (***)
    filter not exists { ?user a ?itemClass }
    optional {
      ?item :hasValueNo ?valueNo
    }
    bind(if(bound(?valueNo), ?valueNo, "default no value") as ?value)
  }
}
```

```
----------------
| item | value |
================
| :i   | 1     |
----------------
```

Now, there's one commented line in that query:

```
#-- ?item ?anyP ?anyO   # (***)
```

If you uncomment that line, you get the results that you'd expect:

```
-----------------------------
| item | value              |
=============================
| :i   | 1                  |
| :j   | "default no value" |
-----------------------------
```

I *think* that what's happening here is that in the second optional case, since there are no triple patterns that introduce bindings (since the **optional** doesn't match), that side of the **union** doesn't get included, *even though* the **bind** would introduce some bindings if the side were allowed to match.  By adding the pattern:

```
?item ?anyP ?anyO
```

to the query, there's at least *something* that will match in that part of the **union**, at which point the rest of the block gets included.  I used **?anyP** and **?anyO** to emphasize that it's arbitrary, but since you already know that the **?item** is an **?itemClass**, you could just include that triple again, i.e., **?item a ?itemClass**.

So, in your case, if you just add

```
?user :likes ?item
```

to the right hand **union** block, you'll get the results that you're expecting:

```
-----------------------------
| item   | suitabilityValue |
=============================
| :item2 | 0                |
| :item1 | 1.5              |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: so i was so close, i tried yours and it is working exactly as needed, thanks as always. There is just one thing, you assumed that `?item` always has a class `?itemClass` which is not necessary, i put them all in one optional, and bind **after** the optional :). thanks again, i appreicate it

Comment: @AniaDavid Yes, in **my** sample data, the item always has a class, so that was a safe line to include that would guarantee a match.  As I said in the answer, in **your** case, a safe line would be `?user :likes ?item`, since you know (from the outer query) that it will always match.

Comment: and that is what I added actually `?user :likes ?item`, thanks again, you are the one